# Tezos wallet displays hex bytes instead of human readable message

Tags: beacon, kukai, temple

Currently I am integrating a solution that requires the user to sign a message in order to verify their identity. The solution is currently based on the [breacon-sdk](https://github.com/airgap-it/beacon-sdk). The message is prefixed with 04 according to [Sign Payload HEX Prefixed With 05](https://docs.walletbeacon.io/guides/sign-payload/#hex-prefixed-with-05) and formatted according to [Generating a signature with Beacon SDK](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/signing/#generating-a-signature-with-beacon-sdk).

The issue we are facing currently is that the message we are displaying to the user is not displayed in a human readable way, instead it is displayed just as hex bytes. Affected wallets are: Temple Mobile, Airgap Wallet, Naan. Other wallets such as Temple browser extension, Kukai, Umami desktop app, Galleon are displaying the message in a human readable way.

Our original raw is:

```
Tezos Signed Message: Welcome to Mailchain!

Please sign to start using this address with Mailchain. This will not trigger a blockchain transaction or cost any gas fees.

What's happening?
A messaging key will be registered with this address and used only for messaging. It will replace any existing registered messaging keys.

Technical Details:
Address: tz1P1xs3qkYNk6cBW273W2UbEVhpWYbwxwZ6
Messaging key: 0xe27bc7aaff2005e0d6530fcff163e046cd450259b1db284680c40cd4388f13017a
Nonce: 14
```

This results in byte payload of:

```
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
```

Can you point me to something wrong in the payload why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

To add the answer from a discussion:

There's nothing wrong with the payload in your example. Ofc it's dangerous with this kind of blind signing. But it's more effort to be human-friendly and apparently easy to get away with it.

But as a user I would be worried if I am signing unknown piece of bytes, i might be signing malicious piece of payload.The question is if there are issue with my payload that the payload is displayed as byte hex array instead of human readable message. Is there some additional prefix/sufix/checksum that needs to be aded for the wallets to interpret it better?

**Nothing you can do on your side to improve it. Need to be improved on the wallet-side.**